# Function causes edit_post_link to link to the wrong post

Tags: functions

In my functions.php I have a function that allows me to place a "[similar posts by categories](http://www.wpcustoms.net/snippets/show-related-posts-by-category/)":

**functions.php:**

```
function alep_related_posts_by_category() {  
global $post;  
// We should get the first category of the post  
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );  
$first_cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;  

$args = array(  
    // It should be in the first category of our post:  
    'category__in' => array( $first_cat ),  
    // Our post should NOT be in the list:  
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),  
    'posts_per_page' => 3  
);  

$posts = get_posts( $args );  
if( $posts ) {  
    $output = '<div class="sidebar-entries">';  

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {  
        setup_postdata( $post );  
        $post_title = get_the_title();  
        $permalink = get_permalink();  
        $output .= '<p class="title clickablediv"><a href="' . $permalink . '" title="' . esc_attr( $post_title ) . '">' . $post_title . '</a></p>';  
    }  
    $output .= '</div>';  
} else {  

    $output .= '<p>Sorry, no other posts matched this category.</p>';  
}  
echo $output;  
}
```

I have just found out that if I use this function together with `<?php edit_post_link('Edit article', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>` it will cause the "Edit post link" to link to the wrong post. I am not sure why these functions are related.
I know that if I remove the function above, the `edit_post_link` will work fine.

So what is going on here? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `wp_reset_postdata()` after looping posts.I think this will solve your problem ...

**Note :** if you use `setup_postdata()` you do need to `wp_reset_postdata()` afterwards.

Comment: So I added `wp_reset_postdata()` after `echo $output;`. Is this what you meant? I mean does it matter where in the code I add it, as long as it is after `setup_postdata()`?